# OpenCL: Expected identifier in kernel

Tags: opencl

I am running the following kernel on windows 7, 64 bit, with Intel CPU and HD graphics.

I get very strange error reporting by `clGetProgramBuildInfo` for the following code:

```
#define BLOCK_SIZE 256

__kernel void reduce4(__global uint* input, __global uint* output, __local uint* sdata) 

{
    unsigned int tid = get_local_id(0);
    unsigned int bid = get_group_id(0);
    unsigned int gid = get_global_id(0);
    unsigned int blockSize = get_local_size(0);

    unsigned int index = bid*(BLOCK_SIZE*2) + tid;
    sdata[tid] = input[index] + input[index+BLOCK_SIZE];
     barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    for(unsigned int s = BLOCK_SIZE/2; s > 64 ; s >>= 1) {
        // Unrolling the last wavefront and we cut 7 iterations of this
        // for-loop while we practice wavefront-programming
        if(tid < s) 
        {
            sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s];
        }
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    }

    if (tid < 64) {
        if (blockSize >= 128) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 64];
        if (blockSize >=  64) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 32];
        if (blockSize >=  32) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + 16];
        if (blockSize >=  16) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid +  8];
        if (blockSize >=   8) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid +  4];
        if (blockSize >=   4) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid +  2];
        if (blockSize >=   2) sdata[tid] += sdata[tid +  1];
    }
    // write result for this block to global mem
    if(tid == 0) 
     {
     output[bid] = sdata[0];
     }
}
```

It always says:

```
Compilation started
:38:2: error: expected identifier or '('
Compilation failed
```

this is for the last line, where I have put }. What is wrong here?

**Update:**

```
This is how I am reading the kernel file:

int offset = 0; 
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfDevices; ++i, ++offset ) {
            /* Load the two source files into temporary datastores */
            const char *file_names[] = {"SimpleOptimizations.cl"}; 
            const int NUMBER_OF_FILES = 1;
            char* buffer[NUMBER_OF_FILES];
            size_t sizes[NUMBER_OF_FILES];
            loadProgramSource(file_names, NUMBER_OF_FILES, buffer, sizes);

            /* Create the OpenCL program object */
            program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, NUMBER_OF_FILES, (const char**)buffer, sizes, &error);             
            if(error != CL_SUCCESS) {
              perror("Can't create the OpenCL program object");
              exit(1);   
            }
```

**Definition of loadProgramSource**

```
void loadProgramSource(const char** files,
                       size_t length,
                       char** buffer,
                       size_t* sizes) {
       /* Read each source file (*.cl) and store the contents into a temporary datastore */
       for(size_t i=0; i < length; i++) {
          FILE* file = fopen(files[i], "r");
          if(file == NULL) {
             perror("Couldn't read the program file");
             exit(1);   
          }
          fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
          sizes[i] = ftell(file);
          rewind(file); // reset the file pointer so that 'fread' reads from the front
          buffer[i] = (char*)malloc(sizes[i]+1);
          buffer[i][sizes[i]] = '\0';
          fread(buffer[i], sizeof(char), sizes[i], file);
          fclose(file);
       }
}
```

Comment: This kind of thing often happens if you are loading kernel code from file and not properly null terminating the buffer. Can you show us how you are doing this?

Comment: OK, but what's in `loadProgramSource`? That's the place where these errors would usually be.

Comment: @jprice Can you suggest a way to check what is in it?

Comment: I thought you might have written that function. Where does it come from - some library or utility header?

Comment: @jprice Oh I am sorry, now I got,  I am pasting the definition in my update now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58056/discussion-between-jprice-and-user2799508).

Comment: Append `//` to the source file should work. Maybe some empty lines works too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is an issue with the way the Windows deals with text files opened with `fopen()`. If you take a look at the [MSDN page for `fopen()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx), it indicates that if you open a file with just `"r"` as the mode string, some translations will happen with regards to line-endings. This means that the size of the file you query may not match the amount of data read by `fread()`.

To solve this, simply change the mode string to indicate that you wish to read the file as binary data (i.e. without any pesky translations):

```
FILE* file = fopen(files[i], "rb");
```

Comment: You are the real MVP. I was struck with the issue one whole Day and was trying all Dumb answers. Thanks to you the issue is solved. Yes definitely the problem was with size of the file..............