# Reading an external kernel in OpenCL

Tags: opencl, external

I have the following lines of code which I use to first determine the file size of the .cl file I am reading from (and loading into a buffer), and subsequently building my program and kernel from the buffer. Assuming calculate.cl contains a simple vector addition kernel.

```js
//get size of kernel source
FILE *f = fopen("calculate.cl", "r");
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
size_t programSize = ftell(f);
rewind(f);

//load kernel into buffer
char *programBuffer = (char*)malloc(programSize + 1);
programBuffer[programSize] = '\0';
fread(programBuffer, sizeof(char), programSize, f);
fclose(f);

//create program from buffer
cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char**) &programBuffer, &programSize, &status);

//build program for devices
status = clBuildProgram(program, numDevices, devices, NULL, NULL, NULL);

//create the kernel
cl_kernel calculate = clCreateKernel(program, "calculate", &status);
```

However, when I run my program, the output produced is zero instead of the intended vector addition results. I've verified that the problem is not to do with the kernel itself (I used a different method to load an external kernel which worked and gave me the intended results) however I am still curious as  to why this initial method I attempted did not work.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem's been solved. 
following bl0z0's suggestion and looking up the error, I've found the solution here:

[OpenCL: Expected identifier in kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971071/opencl-expected-identifier-in-kernel)

thanks everyone :D I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this gives the programing size in terms of the number of chars:

```
size_t programSize = ftell(f);
```

and here you need to allocate in terms of bytes:

```
char *programBuffer = (char*)malloc(programSize + 1);
```

so I think that previous line should be

```
char *programBuffer = (char*)malloc(programSize * sizeof(char) + 1);
```

Double check this by just printing the programBuffer.

Comment: I think that `sizeof(char)` is always 1, but I agree that the code with it looks more like you know what you are doing.

Comment: double checked. the program buffer is being loaded correctly. ^_^